# My webcam flips the picture, how do flip it back?

Tags: 10.10, webcam

On my ASUS ul30vt with Maverick installed I have the problem that the webcam shows the picture flipped. What can I do to make it normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this post](https://lists.launchpad.net/asus-ul30/msg00073.html) on the [Asus UL30 team's](https://launchpad.net/~asus-ul30) mailing list you can use [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libv4l/+archive/ppa) to fix the webcam in 10.04. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be information on how well this works with 10.10.

I recommended joining the team, posting on the mailing list since you'll find a bunch of UL30 owners there, and then updating your progress here so that we can point people to the right information. This information should at least get you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 would be to check for a firmware update for your hardware. I've seen this specific problem corrected in firmware, although not specifically your model. If that doesn't work, look into module "quirks" settings for your video device.