# Webcam image has flipped on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, webcam

For some reason the the image from my webcam has vertically flipped on Ubuntu 16.04. Ideally, I would like to know how I can rotate the image, preferably using some kind of GUI. I haven't been able to find anything online explaining how I can do this.

I realise that there are answers to this question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124774/how-do-i-vertically-flip-my-webcams-image) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6574/my-webcam-flips-the-picture-how-do-flip-it-back), but unfortunately the solutions are no longer valid.

Thanks!

Comment: Which webcam? Does the camera assembly rotate within its frame?

Comment: Is it flipped in all applications, or just in some? Thumbs up to @K7AAY for hinting at a surgical solution, LOL.

Comment: @K7AAY it is a Microsoft HD-3000 Webcam, unfortunately it doesn't rotate in its frame. The image from the webcam was being displayed correctly until recently.

Comment: @zwets It is flipped in all applications

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/lifecam-hd-3000-how-to-change-mirror-image/daab1ce7-6280-4b20-96e0-ba0f0f93a2b5 Microsoft's tech suggested moving it to a different USB port (saying this with a straight face, no doubt.)

Comment: @K7AAY Unfortunately this doesn't help.